# Finding vector from a given subspace

Tags: vector-spaces

Given the subspace described by those three vectors:

$W=lin([1, 0, 2, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 0, 1] ) $
Now i want to pick up any vector that is located in this subspace. How should i do this?

Comment: A vector of the subspace is a linear combination of the subspace's base vectors

Comment: But if it is 4 dimensional this should be linear combination of three of them or four i.e. should i add one vector to this set of vectors?

Comment: Is your $lin$ notation the same as $span$ ?

Comment: W is a three-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$.  This is called a hyperplane.

Comment: yes, yes it is span

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Definition:** The *linear hull*/ *span* of a set $S$ of vectors is the set of all (finite) linear combinations of the vectors in the set.

So, by definition, any vector $v$ in the subspace $\operatorname{lin}\left( \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 2 &4 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 &3 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 &1 \end{bmatrix}\right)$ can be written as a linear combination of those $3$ vectors.  That is:

$$v=\alpha\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 2 &4 \end{bmatrix} + \beta\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 &3 \end{bmatrix} +\gamma\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 &1 \end{bmatrix}$$

where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are real numbers.  So just choose your favorite three numbers, plug them into the above, and add.